Generic.List and .ForEach()
Given that .ForEach(action) doesn't actually RETURN anything, I was hoping to create a function that accepts a Generic List of String and a prefix, that then returns the prefixed generic list, so that I can .AddRange to another Generic List.
This will correctly prefix, and the console output claims I have a generic list of string prior to the return, but what I actually have outside the function is back to being an array. Is there any way to stop Powershell from changing type on me? Or is this just one of those "conveniences" that cause so much trouble?
function PrefixListItems {
    param (
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]$list,
        [String]$prefix
    )
    $return = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

    foreach ($item in $list.ToArray().ForEach({"$prefix$_"})) {
        $return.Add($item)
    }
    Write-Host "in function $($return.GetType())"
    return $return
}
CLS

$first = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@('One', 'Two', 'Three')
Write-Host "in main $((PrefixListItems -list:$first -prefix:'___').GetType())"


$first.ForEach({ Write-Host $args[0] }) will show it is actually enumerating. You're confusing PowerShell's intrinsic .ForEach Method with List<T>'s .ForEach(action<T>). Very different things.

OK, since I want to populate a variable not just dump to the console, is there a way to do that? To actually RETURN something? Or is .ForEach(action<T>) really limited to Print? That seems odd, but yeah, lots of PowerShell and .NET seems crazy to me.

Use a standard loop or .ToArray() into .foreach

Aha! .ToArray() seems to work. But why I can't do that with a Generic List has never been explained. It makes no sense to me that you can't. But hopefully in the next month I can finish this project and not need to care any more. :)

You have asked the exact same question before (linked) and has been closed as a duplicate with other question that explains this.

OK, I edited the question to be totally different but related. I tried to write a function to take a generic list of string and a string to prefix with, and return a generic list of string. And inside the function it looks like it;'s working, but somewhere PowerShell seems to be forcing the return value to be an array again. Grrrrrr@!

return , $list the comma prevents enumeration.

Ah, I should have remembered that. A year in Ukraine doing something VERY different does that I guess. I would ask why on god's green earth anyone would ever want automatic enumeration, but whatever. I have my answer, I'll get this done and I'll move on. Thanks!
